# Delete Record From Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

i am having trouble deleting records off my datagridview as it throws in an error every time i try to delete a record. The error shows "no value given for one or more required paramemters". 
This is my code:

```
 Private Sub delete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles delete.Click
    If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim myPrimaryKey As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("id").Value
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If

            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            'cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM attendance " & intemployeeno
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM VehicleDefects WHERE id=" & myPrimaryKey
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Me.refreshdata()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Select 1 row before you hit Delete")
            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your "id" column probably isn't a numeric datatype, if not you need to wrap "myPrimaryKey" in ticks... Also it's a good idea to take your CommandText and paste it into a dummy query and run it to see what happens and will tell you where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM VehicleDefects WHERE id='" & myPrimaryKey & "'"
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this would work. It would be great as the OP might not understand why this may work or not; you don't explain your answer ... just a thought.

Comment: Umm ... not to be rude, but that is NOT best practice and is prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: Yes I agree that the above fix will not be useful for integer fields

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have problem at  Me.refreshdata()

Show us the code for refreshdata() Subroutine/Function

Comment: i have managed to solve the problem now, it was due to mis spelt column name in the commandtext.

Answer (score 0):

many time  `"no value given for one or more required paramemters".` this error comes due to invalid Column Names. I recommend that please check spell in `cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM VehicleDefects WHERE id=" & myPrimaryKey` line